# Comment and describe my property code only once

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, comments, propertygrid

I'd like to use an xml summary comment of a property to display it also as a propertygrid description. For this I need to define an additional `DescriptionAttribute` which will contain exactly the same text.

Is there a way to accomplish this which would not require me to copy & paste every single comment or description for every single property?

As far as I know the comments are not compiled, so I don't see a way to extract the comments with a custom attribute at runtime. I'm also open to go the other way around if there would be a solution to workaround doubling the comment texts.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// My Description of this property
    /// </summary>
    [Description("My identical Description again - is there a way to only write it once?")]
    public object MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why you need both? Are you generating documentation from the xml comments? If you comments and description are going to be the same, you could remove the xml comments and maintain only the description.

Comment: @Junaith I need it in xml for intellisense and as Description for a propertygrid control.